# How to localize the Date Range Picker?

Tags: internationalization, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-daterangepicker

[image]

I'm using [date ***range*** picker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/) component for choosing date ranges. Does it support **[I18n](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/i18n.html)**?
How can I edit the calendar language into `Traditional Chinese`?

Here is an example snippet of configuration code:

```
// Set the date range picker
$('input[name="daterange-last-30-days"]').daterangepicker({

    // Predefined Ranges
    startDate: moment().subtract('days', 30),
    endDate: moment(),
    "applyClass": "btn-success",
    "cancelClass": "btn-danger",
    locale: {
        format: 'YYYY/MM/DD',
        // Language Setting
        monthNames: ["一月", "二月", "三月", "四月", "五月", "六月", "七月", "八月", "九月", "十月", "十一月", "十二月"],
        daysShort: ["日", "一", "二", "三", "四", "五", "六"]
    }
});
```

Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this [jquery plugin](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Multi-language-jQuery-Date-Range-Picker-Plugin/) for chinese language support with date range picker.

check that link if it helps...

Comment: Thanks, but I want to keep the original style and change the language settings only.

Comment: that is also possible with your daterange picker please check this http://jsfiddle.net/r21747qc/170/

Comment: i think problems is with your locale section apply locale like this            "locale": {
        "format": "MM/DD/YYYY",
        "separator": " - ",
        "applyLabel": "Apply",
        "cancelLabel": "Cancel",
        "fromLabel": "From",
        "toLabel": "To",
        "customRangeLabel": "Custom",
        "daysOfWeek": ["日", "一", "二", "三", "四", "五", "六"],
        "monthNames": ["一月", "二月", "三月", "四月", "五月", "六月", "七月", "八月", "九月", "十月", "十一月", "十二月"],
        "firstDay": 1
    }

Comment: That helps! Works perfectly. :)